# xflock4 triggers standy instead of locking the screen

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04

How do I get the standard behaviour for ctrl+alt+del back? When I use the combination standy is triggered instead of screen lock.

Answer (score 0):

Open

> xfce4-keyboard-settings

(with terminal or press alt+f2 and paste the command)

You should get this windows:

[image]

Here you can determine the xflock4 shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that xflock4 triggers suspend. I know where to change the shortcut.

Comment: Sorry i've misunderstood this. What happens if you run xflock4 from terminal ? Does this trigger also an suspend ? Did you update your system (from 13.10 or another version) or is this a fresh installation ?

Comment: OK I think I know what this is caused by. I run Xubuntu on my Notebook and the lid is closed usually because I use an external monitor. If I have the lid open and lock it works fine.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. If this disturbs you, try to change the settings here "xfce4-power-manager-settings"